# How to put superscript google chart title?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, charts, google-visualization

I have the next code

```
var title = 'hello<sup>2</sup>';
```

Now I'm using [google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) and I want the `2` appear as a superscript.

I get

```
hello<sup>2</sup>
```

the code on the title is

```
<text text-anchor="start" x="148" y="52.9" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" font-weight="bold" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">Hello<sup>2</sup></text>
```

which is on a svg, now I tried, the next

```
var title = 'hello<text style="vertical-align: super">2</text>';
```

but I get

```
hello<text style="vertical-align: super">2</text>
```

Any ideas of how can I put the `2` as superscript?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method (if you just want to do this for title) is to make a separate div which contains text for the title in HTML. If you do want to do it within Google Charts natively, you will need to write javascript that will manipulate the title svg.

To create superscript in SVG, you can see [this article](http://www.svgbasics.com/font_effects_italic.html). As you can see, you would need the SVG to change your title text to something like this:

```
<svg viewBox = "0 0 500 300" version = "1.1">
    <desc>
        Text example
    </desc>
    <g fill = "navy">
        <text x = "10" y = "25" font-size = "20">
            <tspan>
                e = mc
                <tspan baseline-shift = "super">
                    2
                </tspan>
            </tspan>
            <tspan x = "10" y = "60">
                T
                <tspan baseline-shift = "sub">
                    i+2
                </tspan>
                =T
                <tspan baseline-shift = "sub">
                    i
                </tspan>
                + T
                <tspan baseline-shift = "sub">
                    i+1
                </tspan>
            </tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

So in your case, you can try finding the text for your title, and manipulating the SVG using jquery. Of course, it will be much easier to just make a separate `<div>` with an HTML title, but the choice is yours.

Comment: It doesn't work chec here https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#bar_chart if you add `<tspan>
                e = mc
                <tspan baseline-shift = "super">
                    2
                </tspan>
            </tspan>` code on `title:`, you will see what I mean.

Comment: @Jeff Maybe my answer was difficult to understand, but I was not saying you could use the `title` option to do this. I specifically said you should make a separate element (a `<div>` other than the chart), or javascript to manipulate the SVG of the completed chart element.

Answer (score 0):

`<sup>` is not a valid SVG element.

Try this instead:

```
var title = 'hello<tspan dy="-0.5em" font-size="0.7em">2</tspan>';
```

Comment: It doesn't work https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#bar_chart if you add your code on `title:`, you will see what I mean.

Comment: You didn't say you wanted to put it in the JSON chart definition.  It looks like the 'title' string is being HTML-escaped (as it should be for security reasons).  You probably cannot do it that way.